# Can I use the EF 75-300 lens on a Canon T6?

Tags: slr

I have only the Canon 18-55mm lens for my 1300D. I want to buy an EF 75-300mm lens. Will I be having a problem using those lenses?

Comment: Yes, there will be a problem. The 75-300 is an unquestionably awful lens. Don't buy it - save up the small amount more and buy the 55-250.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but you also seem confused about which camera you own - the 1300D is the T6, not the T6i. The answer is the same though.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I'm sure you could put that comment as answer!

Comment: As @PhilipKendall said, but also consider a secondhand 55-250 IS which I see are reasonably cheap - undoubtedly a much better lens even when compared optically to much more expensive lenses.

Comment: In the U.S. a used EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 II (or the STM version) in excellent condition can be had for less than $100. There's no excuse for buying the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III instead. No one in their right mind would ever consider using that lens on a FF body if they later moved from APS-C to FF. (If you find a used copy of the EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 IS, that is a completely different optical formula that was the precursor of the current EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 which is on par with the 55-250mm or the non-L 70-300mm lenses.)

Comment: @MichaelClark ' No one in their right mind would ever consider using that lens on a FF body' Both the mark I and Mark III are sitting in a cupboard at my parents... I really want to give it a go now!

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'Mark *anything*' Canon lens. Only second and subsequent models of a series of Canon *bodies* include 'Mark' in the name. Second and subsequent lenses with the same focal length(s), maximum aperture(s), and focusing motor type have Roman numerals: 'II', 'III', 'IV', etc. Neither camera bodies nor lenses have a Roman numeral 'I' in the model name.

Comment: @MichaelClarkin that case I have access to the original and the third iteration...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both the Canon 1300D and the Canon T6i have an EF-S camera mount. This means they are compatible with all EF-S and EF lenses.